# Not receiving mails from Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, email

i want the visitors to be able to send a contact form to the admin email and i am able to do it locally and received emails but when i uploaded the project to the cpanel and tried to send emails emails will go through to the database but not receiving anything in my mail box

this is env:

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

this is mail:

```
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],


'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

is there anything wrong in my code that preventing my inbox to receive mails?
keep in mind that when i send a form i will get the "success" message and get the info in database but not receiving in my mail inbox

Comment: have you checked spam folder ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir i did, nothing is there

Comment: do you run workers?

Comment: @Dry7 sorry, i don't know what do you mean by that